# Magento: How do I move my categories faster

Tags: magento

I have hundred of categories and sub-categories that were done entered earlier. I want to know able to consolidate them and move them to a more logical order. However the adminhtml, each move takes a long time.

I have already disabled the catalog_rewrite_url to Manual mode. Can I go disable anything esle programatically to make this faster.

Alternatively is there any way i can programatically change all of them into the new order.

(P.S. I am sorry if this is the wrong forum to ask this)

Comment: Here is the answer in this thread, [http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22710/](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22710/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

[Magento - Move a category programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986344/magento-move-a-category-programmatically)

You could work out all the moves you want and put together a little script to do it all for you.

You might also want to clear out the catalog_rewrite_url table completely (if you are on a dev environment). This can be rebuilt (its in index). In that way the old URL redirects won't have to be written.

Actually, if you are on dev, try clearing this table out anyway to see how it speeds up using normal admin.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After examining the code I just changed js code so that user will see that category is moved in category tree but actual php backend job will be processing for some time. To do that. you need to override:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category/tree.phtml
```

change js ajax request code like this:

```
new Ajax.Request(
    '<?php echo $this->getMoveUrl() ?>',
    {
        method:     'POST',
        parameters: pd.join(""),
        onCreate: function(request) {
            console.log('onCreate()');
            Ajax.Responders.unregister(varienLoaderHandler.handler);
        },
        onComplete: function(request) {
            console.log('onComplete()');
            Ajax.Responders.register(varienLoaderHandler.handler);
        },
        onSuccess : success,
        onFailure : failure
    }
);
```

With this screen will not be blocked by js when actual moving is made. Also you will be able to move multiple categories while one is already being moved.
Code is not complete. You will need to restrict that category cannot be moved to already moving category and some other constraints.

But if you know what you're doing everything will be ok. :)